# Uploading python development enviroments library to Hi3519 SoC (System on Chip)

Tags: python, arm, embedded, python-embedding

I have a License plate recognition system which is written in python, and it uses openCV and OpenALPR as the main libraries along with other additional libraries.

In my possession I have a Hi3519 SOC (system on chip) and I would like to upload the python code onto the chip. Cross compiling python to C/C++ would not work.
I've been suggested to upload the python development environment libraries onto the chip and then upload the LPR (license plate recognition) system which is written in python.

Can someone assist me on how to upload the development libraries onto the chip?

Comment: Translating or re-implementing to C or C++ is _not_ "cross-compiling".  And compiled Python is not C or C++,  and C/C++ is not a thing - it is either C or C++ not both.   Python requires an extensive run-time (the interpreter) and any libraries your application uses and does not run "stand-alone" if your platform runs Linux, and has access to the internet, then installing Python support and the libraries should be straightforward using the platforms package manager.  If the platform does not run Linux or an OS with a Python implementation, then you used the wrong language!

Comment: I think the [vendor's support](http://www.hisilicon.com/en/support) should be your first port of call.  HiSilicon do not appear to make much more than a data brief available to non-customers - perhaps you have more information (and the SDK)?

Comment: Hi Clifford, as for the SDK I don't have it. The only thing which was provided was the toolchain (arm-hisiv500-linux), which allows me to upload the algorithm via telnet or SSH